# JQ getting terminal unique values and filtering by keys

Tags: json, key, jq

I am discovering jq and it is amazing stuff. Posted some on GitHub and they told me to post usage question here.

I am trying to get a list of key/value from a json and filter to keep unique value per keys that belong to a list/array.
input json is

```
{
"key0": {
"key1": "valueA",
"key2": 123456,
"key3": [{
  "key4": "anotherValue41",
  "key5": "anotherValue51",
  "key6": 999
}, {
  "key4": "anotherValue42",
  "key5": "anotherValue52",
  "key6": 666
}],
    "key10": {
        "key11": "lastvalue"
    }
}
}
```

my keyList is

```
["key1","key2","key4","key5","key6","key9","key11"]
```

expected result is to retain only key/values that match with the keylist and to group the values by the keys.

```
{
"key1": ["valueA"],
"key2": [123456],
"key4": ["anotherValue41", "anotherValue42"],
"key5": ["anotherValue51", "anotherValue52"],
"key6": [999, 666],
"key11": "lastvalue"
}
```

I have tried to use keys but I cannot revert back to the values… All other samples I have found have repeating json structures.

I hope I am clear enough.

Thanks
Cyril

Comment: don't forget to accept and up-vote answers that provide you with help solving your problem OR comment about problems you are having with those answers. An interesting problem, but in the future please include your attempt to solve your problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's focus on solving the problem without worrying about keyList.

This can be done conveniently using `tostream` and the following helper function:

```
# s should be a stream of [key, value] pairs
def aggregate(s):
 reduce s as $x ({}; .[$x[0]] += [$x[1]] );
```

The main filter can then be written as:

```
aggregate( tostream
  | select(length==2 and (.[0][-1] | type == "string"))
  | [.[0][-1], .[1]] )
```

As it happens, this produces the result for the original problem:

```
{
  "key1": [
    "valueA"
  ],
  "key11": [
    "lastvalue"
  ],
  "key2": [
    123456
  ],
  "key4": [
    "anotherValue41",
    "anotherValue42"
  ],
  "key5": [
    "anotherValue51",
    "anotherValue52"
  ],
  "key6": [
    999,
    666
  ]
}
```

### keyList

To satisfy the requirement about keyList, let's suppose the list is made available as `$keyList`.

Then we can achieve the desired result by simply adding one more `select` condition using `index`:

```
aggregate( tostream
  | select(length==2 and (.[0][-1] | type == "string"))
  | [.[0][-1], .[1]]
  | select(.[0] as $k | $keyList|index($k) ))
```

Comment: this is great ! Thanks man. Could you elaborate or point me to some doc to fully understant the [.[0][-1], .[1]] and the select(length==2 and (.[0][-1] | type == "string")) ? Thank you again. You rock

Comment: I'd start with the tutorial https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/ and then skim the manual for the parts that seem most relevant.  I'd be glad for any feedback regarding: https://github.com/pkoppstein/jq/wiki/A-Stream-oriented-Introduction-to-jq